# Vaadin - How to customize MenuBar to look like links

Tags: java, css, vaadin, vaadin7

I understand that this is done in CSS (well SCSS) but I'm struggling with how to style it so that the `MenuBar` looks like text. I'm ok with the `MenuItems` as they are, I just want the `MenuBar` itself to look like links. A good example is the Help link at the top of StackOverflow, just to the left of the search box at the top of the screen..

By default in Vaadin it looks like buttons, and when I click on them the button is highlighted and has this extra border color as shown below:

[image]

I want to remove all that and just make it look like a link that you click on. The MenuItem styling is great, but I just want to make it look like text. I like the down carrot, as well as the styling for the MenuItems, it's just the MenuBar that I'd like to change. Below is an example:

[image]

I've been messing around with the css for a bit now and I just can't get the right style. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Again I'm just looking to remove the styling of the `MenuBar` and nothing else. So far I have:

```
  .myMenuBar
  {
    border: none;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: myBackgroundColor;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
```

The problem is that there are still a number of style elements I'm struggling with:

[image]

For example I still have a blue highlighted button when I click. Also the popup menu is backgrounded to my custom color. I also have a separator line in black between the two elements. And although it's harder to see there is a fine white and grey line above and below the `MenuBar` to show some depth.

UPDATE: Added some css improvements but I'm still a ways away.

Comment: why don't you start with modifying valo from something that is closer to this style in general?  see https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/ and https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo/tree/master/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes for inspiration, https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/themes.valo.html#themes.valo.variables for possible switches. TBH i find this "build me a CSS for my design" not a good question for SO.

Comment: That's what I tried. I also looked at: https://vaadin.com/api/valo/ Even then I still couldn't figure it out. I did however find a solution which I'm going to post in a second which could be done in code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with the links in the comments just below the question I still struggled to find a solution. Eventually I ran into the Class `ValoTheme` and found I could do exactly what I wanted with one line of code. In fact it was better than what I was planning so kudos to the theme designers!

```
menuBar.setStyleName(ValoTheme.MENUBAR_BORDERLESS);
```